# google sites form depends on the condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-sites

I build a site in Google Sites, and I want to add a Google form based on a selection dropdown.
I tried do to it with an HTML script, but the  part seems to do nothing (I tried also to test it with a  with alert).
Anyone have a solution or an idea?

I expect the user can choose an option from the dropdown list, and according to his choice - the correct form will appear.

Comment: Are you using the new Google site or the classic one? Because, base on the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites), Google Apps script is available only for `Google Sites (classic)`.

Comment: @GiselleValladares I use the new one. Do you have any idea hoe to do that?

Comment: The only idea I can come up with is to create a form with different sections. The first section with the dropdown with the form options, and a section for each of those selections. After that, you set the option to `Go to section base on answer` (Google HC [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062)) from the first section. If you are interested in this option, I can add an answer with a demo on how to do it.

Comment: @GiselleValladares 
I planned to do this, but I tried to find an easier way.
Thank you!